# Retrieving the image of a user through Microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to fetch the image of a user based on email id from microsoft graph API.
I am able to get the details of the logged in user using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value .

What i need is image of another user based on email id. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Ref: [Microsoft Graph API Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below api from the graph explorer to get the photo

1. Goto Graph explorer page

[Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

2. Paste the below api with email id of the user

> `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<email id>/photo/$value`

It will retrieve photo of the user.